# Hacked htaccess file in WordPress

Tags: security

I keep getting my .htaccess file hacked on my WordPress installation, what can I do to prevent this from happening again?

http://pastebin.com/H54FaA8U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com)'s **[wordpress tag](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=wordpress)** for guidance here, and [this question in particular](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/477/protecting-wordpress-installations).

Answer (score 0):

Add this htaccess code in your WordPress .htaccess file to Protect .htaccess and wp-config.php file From Unauthorized Access

```
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</Files>

<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. change your user name and password add tough password that has number and digit and character caps etc.
2. remove all the extra templates, One of you template files are infected that is re writing the htaccess file.
3. Update all the plugins and templates that you are using.
4. remove all the extra plugins that you no longer use.

it worked for me good luck